# Вывод данных из столбца mySQL для С# в массив

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть база данных с колонкой типа `CHAR`и переменная `string[]` Нужно вывести данные из колонки в переменную. Подключаюсь при помощи следующего кода

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionDate);
MySqlCommand Query = new MySqlCommand(); // С помощью этого объекта выполняются запросы к БД
Query.Connection = connection; // Присвоим объекту только что созданное соединение
try
{
    connection.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Соединение установлено!");
}
//здесь нужен код для вывода данных
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект, который ссылается на контекст, засунь в foreach и в цикле выполняй :

List<string> str = new List<string>();
string[] str2;
foreach(var record in contextObject){
str.Add(record.твойСтолбец);
}
string[] str2 = new string[str.Count];
for(int i=0;i != str.Count;i++){
str2[i]=str[i];
}

Comment: Добавил код подключения. Не могу понять какой объект добавлять. (П.с. Понимаю всю глупость вопроса, но сроки жмут(( И возможно кому-то в бушующем пригодится.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651318/mysql-connection-string-c-sharp - Там в ответе есть while.Пробуй работать с rdr c ответа.